# Updating progressbar in parallel loop

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar, task-parallel-library

I have a WinForm application and I am trying to update a progressbar in a parallel loop. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(files, (file, state) =>
        {
           //Intialization of parameters

            //do cpu-intensive task
            DoWork();

            UpdateProgress();
        });



 int counter = 0;
 private object updateLock = new object();

void UpdateProgress()
    {
        lock (updateLock)
        {
            counter++;


            if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
            {

                progressBar1.Invoke(() => { progressBar1.SetProgress(counter); });
            }
            else
            {
                progressBar1.SetProgress(counter);
            }


        }
    }
```

To get an instant update on progressbar animation I use the `SetProgress`.

```
 public static void SetProgress(this ProgressBar bar, int value)
    {
        if (value == bar.Maximum)
        {

            bar.Maximum = value + 1;
            bar.Value = value + 1;
            bar.Maximum = value;
        }
        else
        {
            bar.Value = value + 1;
        }

        bar.Value = value;
    }
```

The whole process seems to work fine, but I have a problem with the way progress bar is updated. Randomly I see the progress animations is set back and forth, say e.g go to 33/150, then to 31/150 and then to 32/150. Although I used a synchonization lock object to update progress on each step accordingly, it seems the messages in Main UI Thread are not processed in order or there is something wrong with the code.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE]**

[image]

Comment: I strongly suggest to move the progressbar update calls outside the lock statement. Currently, you block a counter increase during a long-term progressbar update (UI thread switch!). Locked regions should be as short as possible. Depending on how long your `DoWork` method takes, the UI thread switch to update the progressbar may take longer. Sometimes it is better to poll the counter in an e.g. 300ms interval using a timer and update the progressbar afterwards. You may also have a look to the fast `Interlocked.Increment`method.

Comment: @KBO Thanks for the suggestion, but does it have to do anything with this behavior? What I'm assuming is that by moving the progressbar update calls out of lock region, the race condition increase considerably. In the current counter increase during a long-term progressbar update by locking, it seems that progress is set back and forth at some random point in each run.

Comment: You also assign the `bar.Maximum` twice and then the progressbar maximum is less the the value. That may also cause that behaviour. You should remove the line `bar.Maximum = value;`

Comment: @KBO  "Depending on how long your DoWork method takes, the UI thread switch to update the progressbar may take longer", does this longer update means that the next update on progress animation might be observed sooner than the previous one?

Comment: Try to log the value of `counter` before calling `SetProgress`. It will help you see if the update of the progress bar is not in FIFO order, or something else goes weird.

Comment: @Nick Thanks, but I tried that too, the value of counter adds up sequentially and is is order- i.e. 40, 41, 42, ... . It's at the UI rendering of progressbar when animation goes back and forth 41 ,40, 42, ... .

Comment: Then obivously, updates of the progress bar are out of order.  If I were you, I would forget about the counter variable and the lock.  Change `SetProgress` to `IncrementProgress` and there just update the value of the progress bar + 1, and the maximum if necessary.  Since it will be executed on the UI thread, there will be no need for a lock and to synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related with how [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) works. You may think that it uses only background threads to do the work, but it actually uses the current thread too. In other words during the execution of the `Parallel.ForEach`, the current thread plays the role of a worker thread. In your case the current thread is the UI thread. The condition `if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)` evaluates to `true` for the background threads involved in the operation, and `false` for the UI thread.

The background threads are calling the `progressBar1.Invoke` method in your example. Unlike the [`BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke), the [`Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke) is a blocking method, and will return only after the UI thread has processed the supplied delegate. Since the UI thread is busy processing its own partition of the `files` collection, the `Invoke` will block, so all background threads will get stuck, and the only thread that will continue making progress will be the UI thread. At the end the UI thread will have to wait for the other threads to deliver the result of the single file they received initially for processing, which they won't be able to do, so the `Parallel.ForEach` will deadlock. At least this is the expected outcome of the code you posted. Since you are not observing a deadlock, my guess is that there is some line of code missing in your example (a call to `Application.DoEvents` maybe?) that resolves the deadlock situation.

The easiest way to fix this unpleasant situation is by preventing the UI from becoming a worker thread. Just use the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method, to offload the whole parallel processing to a `ThreadPool` thread:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(//...
});
```

You will also have to mark your event handler with the `async` keyword, otherwise the compiler will not permit the usage of the nifty [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator.

After applying this fix, you may want to make your code more elegant by removing all this ugly `InvokeRequired`/`Invoke` stuff, and replacing it with a modern [`Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) object. This would also make trivially easy to seperate the files-processing logic from the UI-related logic, if you find it desirable from an architectural perspective. You can read [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) article if you want to learn how to use the `Progress` class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, actually I have already offloaded the whole parallel work to a background worker, but the problem persists.

Comment: Hmmm. In this case I can't reproduce the problem. I suggest that you update your question with a reproducible example of the issue you are observing.